# React passing data into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read through the other posts.

I need to pass the cartLength variable into the `shopbanner.js` component, it needs to be imported from `shop.js`

```
shop.js

export default function Shop() {
var cartLength = cart.length;

return (
    ...
  );
}
```

```
shopbanner.js

import {cartLength} from '../pages/shop.js'

export default function ShopBanner() {
  return ( 
    <p>{cartLength}</p>
    <img src="/basket.png"/>
  );
}
```

Turns out I was way overcomplicating things thank you for your answers guys!

Comment: `<ShopBanner cartLength={cartLength} />` | `function ShopBanner({ cartLength })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take cart length as an argument:

```
export default function ShopBanner(cartLength) {
  return ( 
    <p>{cartLength}</p>
    <img src="/basket.png"/>
  );
}
```

Then you can use it like a prop:

```
<ShopBanner cartLength={cart.length}>
```

Comment: This worked so perfectly, and it was so simple! I can't believe I didn't think of this! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use React's props argument.
Add a props argument to the ShopBanner function.
Then you can simply do:

```
<ShopBanner cartLength=.... />
```

And then you can refrence the cartLength as props.cartLength in the ShopBanner's code.

Comment: Thanks I didn't think of using props in this way, even though it's so simple

Answer (score 1):

You should pass it as props or through some kind of state manger.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of somethings so simple